# Are the iPhone 7 EarPods longer?

Tags: iphone

I just got an iPhone 7 Plus and noticed that the EarPod's cable is much longer than the one I had with the iPhone 6s.

Do both the iPhone 7 and the 7 Plus come with longer earphone cables than the 6s and the 6s Plus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question - if you see that they are longer, then they are obviously shipped with longer headphones - but for everyone else, I compared them.

The distance from the cord split to the ends of the headphones is the same; however, the distance from the edge of the connector to the split is approximately two inches longer on the iPhone 7 (Lightning connector) EarPods than on the iPhone 6s EarPods.

[image: Comparison of EarPods shipped with iPhone 7, on left, and iPhone 6s, on right, showing the latter are a couple of inches longer]

Comment: Is it longer because I got the Plus? Or are all iPhone 7 earphones this long.

Comment: @AndrewWarner As noted in my answer I tested with iPhone 7, not Plus.

Answer (score 1):

yes. It is longer for both iPhone 7 and 7 plus.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions